# Entity Framework - Get derived types when querying base by primary key?

Tags: entity-framework

I've read a lot of articles about this and haven't found a clear answer. Here's what I want to do:

I have a base entity (baseEntity) and two inherited entities (House) and (Lizard). I have another entity (myEntity) and an association between the base entity and myEntity, where there is a navigation property on myEntity that goes back to the base entity. All I want to do is, somehow, get an object of the type of the derived entity that the navigation property points to. For example if I follow this path I want: myEntity > navigation property "baseEntity" > get either House or Lizard depending on which one the primary key exists for since both entity types share a primary key value that actually exists in baseEntity.

And just to be clear - I know it can tell the type of the derived class, because when I get an object of baseEntity back from a find operation, or following the navigation property, I can look call .GetType() on that object and it will say either Lizard_C4BDJSNBI498348FHDJ..... or House.... and so on. If I do .GetType().BaseType on that object it will straight up say ModelNamespace.Lizard or ModelNamespace.House.

Any ideas?

[image: Entity Data Model Designer]

Anybody here?

Answer (score 0):

```
var house = myEntity.baseEntity as House;
var lizard = myEntity.baseEntity as Lizard;

if( null != house )
{
    // is a house
}
else if( null != lizard )
{
    // is a lizard
}
else
{
    // is neither a house nor a lizard
}
```

of

```
if( myEntity.baseEntity is House )
{
    // is a house
}
else if( myEntity.baseEntity is Lizard )
{
    // is a lizard
}
```

Comment: I've actually already done this. I was wondering if there was a better way anyone else could think of. Does something like an interface make sense here, implementing some set of properties on the interface so we don't have to know the exact type to be able to work with it, since the foreign key property is on the subclasses classes? Would an interface work better since all necessary properities could just be put in there and it would "combine" the abstract base class and the subclasses?